# Where to find an updated PMS name list

Tags: pantone

Where can I find an updated list with all the **NAMES** of the 1867 PMS colors?

I can't find any updated list online

Answer (score 1):

It may be a copyrights violation to share that information online. Pantone requires everyone to purchase very expensive swatch books for a reason.

Does their online Color Finder help you in any way?
https://www.pantone.com/color-finder

Comment: Another link from Pantone: http://www.pantone.com/how-to-get-pantone-color-manager. Some years ago this libraries for Corel and Adobe were free. u_u

Answer (score 0):

This is dated March 9 2017, not sure if it is true, but worth a look: http://www.printingassoc.com/pmscolor.html

Also, take a look to the image below (click for full size):
[image]